# PANIC: Could not open: Device in ubuntu android studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am new to android Studio(Linux). I referred lot regarding this issue but without luck.

I created the avd from avd manager. When i try to start the emulator, It gives the following error.

Waiting for device.

```
/home/user/Documents/BFS/Softwares/android-studio/sdk/tools/emulator -avd DeviceL -netspeed full -netdelay none
PANIC: Could not open: DeviceL
```

I checked the `usr/.android/avd Path both DeviceL.ini and DeviceL.avd` are there

and also i created the avd from commandline and tried to start, still the same error.
I already set the Variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME =user/path/softwares/android-studio`

could anyone help me with this?
Thank you.